# Need help to create a custom button in swing

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, custom-component, graphics2d

I am trying to create a button which looks as shown below and continuously fades in and fades out .It looks like :-

[image]

Now i have done till the looks with gradient paint but what should i do to make the button text appear.Inspite of calling 'super(s)' it doesn't appear as i have painted it with GradientPaint.What should i do make the text appear over paint.My code is shown below :-

```
import java.awt.AlphaComposite;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.GradientPaint;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;


public class Fader extends JFrame{
Fader()
{
    super("A fading button");
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    setSize(400,400);

    add(new CustomButton("Submit"));
    setVisible(true);
}
public static void main(String args[])
{
SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){public void run(){new Fader();}});
}
}

class CustomButton extends JButton
{
public CustomButton(String s) {
    super(s);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}
public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
{
    super.paintComponent(g);
    Graphics2D g2=(Graphics2D)g.create();
    GradientPaint gp=new GradientPaint(0, 0, Color.RED, 200, 100, Color.YELLOW);
    g2.setPaint(gp);
    g2.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
}
public Dimension getPreferredSize()
{
    return new Dimension(200,100);
}
}
```

Secondly,an advice to implement the fade in and out effect is also requested.

Comment: please to  [check](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[java]+[swing]+[jbutton]+custom) and very good [questions and answers by @mre](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user:584862+[jbutton])

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this option,  that paints a transparent color gradient on a component:

```
@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
    super.paintComponent( g );

    Graphics2D g2=(Graphics2D)g.create();
    int h = getHeight();
    int w = getWidth();

    g2.setComposite(AlphaComposite.getInstance(
            AlphaComposite.SRC_OVER, .5f));
    g2.setPaint(new GradientPaint(0, 0, Color.yellow, 0, h, Color.red));
    g2.fillRect(0, 0, w, h);

    g2.dispose();
}
```

[image]

Other pretty good example with fading in (as requested). I used `RadialGradientPaint`. You can play with `AlphaComposite`

```
g2.setComposite(AlphaComposite.getInstance(AlphaComposite.SRC_OVER, .4f));
```

where `4f` represent transparent level 40%

```
@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
    super.paintComponent( g );

    Graphics2D g2=(Graphics2D)g.create();
    int h = getHeight();
    int w = getWidth();

    g2.setComposite(AlphaComposite.getInstance(AlphaComposite.SRC_OVER, .5f));


    Point2D center = new Point2D.Float(100, 50);
    float radius = 150;
    float[] dist = {0.0f, 1.0f};

    Color[] colors = {Color.yellow, Color.red};
    RadialGradientPaint p = new RadialGradientPaint(center, radius, dist, colors);
    g2.setPaint(p);     

    g2.fillRect(0, 0, w, h);

    g2.dispose();       

}
```

[image]

Finally we can play with alpha dynamically. Her is the full code. I created simple thread that change me alpha from 0 to 9 and vise versa. Here we go:

```
public class Fader extends JFrame{
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
static JButton button;

public static float mTransparent = .0f;

Fader(){
    super("A fading button");
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    setSize(400,400);

    JButton button = new CustomButton("Submit");

    add(button);
    setVisible(true);

    Blink blink = new Blink(this);
    blink.start();
}

public static void main(String args[]){
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){public void run(){new Fader();}});
}

public static float getTransparentLevel() {
    return mTransparent;
}

public  void setTransparentLevel(float newVal) {
    mTransparent = newVal;

    if(button != null){
        button.repaint();

    }
    repaint();


}
}


class Blink extends Thread{

Fader fader;

public Blink(Fader fader) {
    this.fader = fader;
}

@Override
public void run(){

    while(true){        

        if(Fader.getTransparentLevel() == 0.0f){                
            //increase to 1f
            for(int i=1; i<10; i++){
                fader.setTransparentLevel((float)i/10);

                try {
                    Thread.sleep(100);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }               
        }
        else if(Fader.getTransparentLevel() == 0.9f){
            //increase to 1f
            for(int i=10; i>=0; i--){
                fader.setTransparentLevel((float)i/10);

                try {
                    Thread.sleep(100);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }       
    }       
}
}


class CustomButton extends JButton {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
public CustomButton(String s) {
    super(s);       
}

@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
    super.paintComponent( g );

    Graphics2D g2=(Graphics2D)g.create();
    int h = getHeight();
    int w = getWidth();

    g2.setComposite(AlphaComposite.getInstance(AlphaComposite.SRC_OVER, Fader.getTransparentLevel()));


    Point2D center = new Point2D.Float(100, 50);
    float radius = 150;
    float[] dist = {0.0f, 1.0f};

    Color[] colors = {Color.yellow, Color.red};
    RadialGradientPaint p = new RadialGradientPaint(center, radius, dist, colors);
    g2.setPaint(p);     
    g2.fillRect(0, 0, w, h);
    g2.dispose();       

}

public Dimension getPreferredSize(){
    return new Dimension(200,100);
}
}
```

It blinks with sleep 300 ms from .0 to .9 of transparent and back from .9 to .0:

[image] -->
[image]

Comment: :Exactly what i was looking for.
Can u pls help me with the second part i.e to appear and disappear the button continuously.

Comment: @Naveen I added what you want, suppose its what you interested

Comment: @Fess what if there are multiple buttons of the class `Fader` and I don't want all of them to blink?? Or now I want to fade in and fadeout a textfield? Make an interface: `Fadable` implement a `fadeIn()` and `fadeOut()` method set. Then add `Animatable` interface and make it animate(sounds a little overkill but its OOP ;) )

Comment: @Aniket For sure I didn't use any OO patterns. I took code from Naveen's question. I wanted to demonstrate how to paint a transparent color gradient on a component. For me its crude code but its good response on above question :).

Comment: @Aniket kya aap mujhe tips de sakte ho ki tumne itni badiya swing/java whatever kahan se padhi/seekhi.plz step by step batana ,those steps that you followed for learning from basic.Here in USA ,mere upar bahut pressure rehta h to become the best.

plz post me the advice(steps).Thanx.waiting.

Comment: @Naveen ji, aap chat pe aa sakte ho toh wahi deta hoon advice

Comment: @Aniket Sorry,i didn't know how to use chat option .I tried finding you but it lists programming groups.Can u pls find me and start the chat

Answer (score 2):

Once you override the `paintComponent()` method, you are on your own with drawing the button. So, you will have to draw the text yourself. Something like this will help:

```
g2.setColor(Color.GREEN);
g2.drawString(getText(), 0, 10);
```

The above code must be added after the `fillRect` method. However, you will have to use `FontMetrics` in order to position the text according to the text alignment preferences.

Comment: :Thanx.And any advice on how should i implement that fade in and fade out effect .One way i am thinking is to vary the alpha value continuously,but doesn't know exactly what to do.Any help?

Comment: What do you mean by implementing the fade in effect? Do you want to do the gradient paint yourself?

Comment: By fade in and out i mean that the button appears and disappears contnuously.(maybe varying alpha value from 0 to 1 and back to 0 smoothly)

Comment: no, you never want to do any raw text painting yourself - it's hard to get antialiasing correct.

Answer (score 1):

To fadeIn and fadeOut you will need to implement your own `Animation Sequencer` that runs in a different thread, that will constantly vary the alpha value with a `TimerTask`. Once the value of alpha reaches `0`, it should be incremented back to `100%`.

Also check out the book by Romain Guy: `Filthy Rich Java Clients`

Comment: :I understood partly what u said but doesn't know about how to implement. Can u please provide small code snippet.